# Stop playing sound and volume when application is minimized

Tags: c++, winapi, audio

I was using the `PlaySound` function in one C++ application under Windows.
When this application is running a local var command `PlaySound` and it starts to play a WAV file.

But when you click on the minimize dialog box of my application, the sound continues playing, when the logical rule must be silenced or muted until you maximize the application again.

The question is:

Is there application-state within Windows to detect when application is minimized? 
In order to set the `waveOutSetVolume` function with `0x00 = mute`.

Answer (score 1):

Have your app's window catch the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message and check it for the `SC_MINIMIZE`, `SC_MAXIMIZE`, and `SC_RESTORE` notifications.

Comment: Does Win+D trigger WM_SYSCOMMAND?

Comment: No, it does not, because that feature does not really minimize app windows, it merely brings the Desktop window to the foreground.  It does, however, trigger `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`, `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`, `WM_NCCALCSIZE`, `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`, `WM_MOVE`, `WM_SIZE`, `WM_STYLECHANGING`, and `WM_STYLECHANGED` messages (as captured by Spy++).

Answer (score 1):

Your application will receive a [WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632652%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message when the application window has been minimized or maximized. Check the [WINDOWPOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632612%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) struct in lParam to determine the new state. You can then turn the sound off or on, respectively. (Note: this message is also sent when the window is moved, sent to back, etc. So check the lParam.)

If the application is currently minimized can be checked with [IsIconic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

And I don't find it logical that the sound has to stop playing when the application is minimized. It's a multitasking OS after all. I want it to do things in parallel.